# How to delete all files with 0x00 as content?

Tags: batch-file

My hard drive crashed.  However, I was able to make a partial mirror copy and recovered the files from the copy.  Due to the partial copy, the hex content of many files are just 0x00, although file names and folder locations are correct.

I'd like to delete these corrupted files, starting with 0x00 (let's say 8 bytes of 0x00 to be safe) and leaving me the good ones.

Is there a good way to check the Hex content of the first few bytes of a file, and delete these 0x00 files recursively through all folders, either under linux or windows command prompt?

I know this is not a typical task.  I am sure you pros have a genius way of getting this done in a line or two commands.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [tour]. Please read [ask] a good question. Then provide a [mcve] of the code you are trying to use.  The term Stack Overflow should give you some indication that this is a forum community that helps others with their coding errors. It is not a place to request others to write code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Windows batch-file you can use the `FC` command to do a binary compare of one file to another. In this use case you would first create a dummy file with 8 bytes in it of the same character. You can then pipe the output of the `FC` command to the `FIND` command to count the instances of the binary compare.  Unlike other shell scripting languages that allow you to assign the output of a command directly to a variable, you need to use `FOR /F` command to capture the output of a command to assign it to a variable.  In this instance we want to capture the output of the `FIND` command as it will be telling us how many occurrences of the NULL being at the beginning of the file.  Once you have that number you can then use an `IF` command to see if it is equal to the number of occurrences you are expecting and then use the `DEL` command to remove the file.  The `FOR /R` command is iterating all the files in a directory structure.

```
@echo off
REM CREATE A DUMMY FILE WITH 8 BYTES
set /p ".=AAAAAAAA"<nul>dummy.txt

REM Get all files
FOR /R %%G IN (*.*) DO (
    REM Compare file to dummy file and count instances of NULLS
    FOR /F "delims=" %%H IN ('fc /b "%%G" dummy.txt ^|find /C ": 00 41"') DO (
        REM Check If we have a file that starts with 8 nulls, delete file
        IF "%%H"=="8" ECHO DEL "%%G"
    )
)
```

If you are satisfied with the output on the screen, then remove the `ECHO` to allow the `DEL` command to execute the file removal

Comment: This is smart. I had thought the dummy.txt were intended to have 0x00 in it.  But putting "A" in and use them to generate error output is a smart twist of wisdom.  I think this should work.  But let me try it out for real and report back.   Thank you very much.

Comment: On a side note, is 8 bytes of 0x00 safe enough?  Do any of you know any file types that may start with 8 bytes of 0x00?  I can put a whole sector 512 bytes of 0x00 just to be safe.

Comment: This indeed worked as expected.  Thank you very much, Squashman!